# Invalid SOAP Fault Message only in Mono

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, mono, onvif

I am trying to consume the ONVIF WSDL service on a C#.net application to talk to IP CCTV cameras.

Developing in .NET Visual Studio on Windows, the application runs fine from my command line. Trying to run the same .exe on Mono (Mono JIT compiler version 5.16.0.220 (tarball Mon Nov 26 17:15:30 UTC 2018) on Debian I cannot get the application to work.

I believe the issue is related to the fact on Mono I am receiving a badly formatted SOAP Fault which the application cannot handle. I don't know if the SOAP Fault is caused by the IP camera and Mono cannot handle it properly (in which case I have an error in the error handling, and fixing the root cause whatever that may be would fix it) OR if the SOAP side is actually fine but Mono is just messing up the decoding of my responses.

The below is the error, it looks like the SOAP response contains 'env:faultcode' which is not expecting.

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: Received an invalid SOAP Fault message ---> System.Xml.XmlException: Unexpected node Element name env:faultcode
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageFault.CreateFault12 (System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message message, System.Int32 maxBufferSize) [0x0012c] in <90242c243a054a8a8feb6f7b52756571>:0 
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageFault.CreateFault (System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message message, System.Int32 maxBufferSize) [0x0001c] in <90242c243a054a8a8feb6f7b52756571>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Object.__icall_wrapper_mono_remoting_wrapper(intptr,intptr)
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke) OnvifMonitor.OnvifDeviceMgmt.Device.GetDeviceInformation(OnvifMonitor.OnvifDeviceMgmt.GetDeviceInformationRequest)
  at OnvifMonitor.OnvifDeviceMgmt.DeviceClient.GetDeviceInformation (OnvifMonitor.OnvifDeviceMgmt.GetDeviceInformationRequest request) [0x00007] in <596fa5448c77457ba1f773bf27dbbf2a>:0 
  at OnvifMonitor.MonitoringThread.Connect (System.String ip, System.Int32 port) [0x0013e] in <596fa5448c77457ba1f773bf27dbbf2a>:0 
  at OnvifMonitor.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x0000c] in <596fa5448c77457ba1f773bf27dbbf2a>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: Received an invalid SOAP Fault message ---> System.Xml.XmlException: Unexpected node Element name env:faultcode
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageFault.CreateFault12 (System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message message, System.Int32 maxBufferSize) [0x0012c] in <90242c243a054a8a8feb6f7b52756571>:0 
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageFault.CreateFault (System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message message, System.Int32 maxBufferSize) [0x0001c] in <90242c243a054a8a8feb6f7b52756571>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Object.__icall_wrapper_mono_remoting_wrapper(intptr,intptr)
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke) OnvifMonitor.OnvifDeviceMgmt.Device.GetDeviceInformation(OnvifMonitor.OnvifDeviceMgmt.GetDeviceInformationRequest)
  at OnvifMonitor.OnvifDeviceMgmt.DeviceClient.GetDeviceInformation (OnvifMonitor.OnvifDeviceMgmt.GetDeviceInformationRequest request) [0x00007] in <596fa5448c77457ba1f773bf27dbbf2a>:0 
  at OnvifMonitor.MonitoringThread.Connect (System.String ip, System.Int32 port) [0x0013e] in <596fa5448c77457ba1f773bf27dbbf2a>:0 
  at OnvifMonitor.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x0000c] in <596fa5448c77457ba1f773bf27dbbf2a>:0
```

I don't want to post the full application code as it's pretty long and not sure which part is relevant. However, I have used Visual Studio to "Add Service Reference" of https://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl/devicemgmt.wsdl which is the OnvifDeviceMgmt namespace in the below message.

When my application starts I am making a simple request to GetDeviceInformation which should return some generic info to the app. Authentication is passed on, following the examples from https://github.com/thephez/onvif-interface and using some guidance for this based on the code here.

I'll reiterate, this works FINE on Windows but Mono seems to behave differently.

Any ideas on how I could further debug the Soap error? Can I somehow tell it to ignore Soap errors and pass them on, or figure out what's causing the difference?

Comment: To debug use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  Compare working and non working.  The http message has a header and usually the issue is the c# application need to add a missing header.  Often the header contains ti IE compatibility and a different default IE is being used.

Comment: The error message just indicates the response had a fault code and does not give any details why the server responded with a fault.

Comment: I'll try and see if I can wireshark on the Linux box.

I guessed the error message indicates the response has a fault, but SoapUI and Windows seem to send the same message as the Linux command and work fine... (I am writing the 'BeforeSendRequest' "transmitted" message out to console and comparing)

Comment: You should be able to capture linux box data from Windows as long as they are physically on same subnet.